# Showing image from js blur

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've initially displayed the image and I change it to another image and when I re-change it back, the image is a little bit blur. How do I make not getting blur? Thanks for your help.

HTML

```
        <div>
          <img src="./images/image-product-1.jpg" class=" w-100 main-img" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class=" d-flex mt-4 justify-content-center">
          <img src="./images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg" class="  thumbnail t-1" alt="">
          <img src="./images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg" class="  thumbnail t-2" alt="">
          
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
             let thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
             let mainImg = document.getElementsByClassName("main-img")[0];
             thumbnail.forEach(function(x){
             x.addEventListener('click',function(e){
             if(e.target.classList.contains("t-1")) {
             mainImg.src = document.getElementsByClassName("t-1")[0].src;}

             else if(e.target.classList.contains("t-2")){
             mainImg.src = document.getElementsByClassName("t-2")[0].src;}


             })
              })
```

Comment: I don't see any blurred image. Seems like you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Also, why do you go for `document.getElementsByClassName("t-1")[0]` when you already use `e.target`? `e.target.src` will do as well. Any BTW try always to use `Event.currentTarget` - unless needed otherwise, and that's 99% of the time in combination with *closest()*: `e.target.closest("someSelector")`

Comment: thanks @RokoC.Buljan I found what's causing my image blur. That's the url problem

Comment: I still don't get your problem. Should the question remain open? If you got to the source of the blurring image issue, you can always delete the question.